Is this a galaxy?
I took a photo last night (Wed 3 July 2024) around 23:45 (BST) from a small town outside of Chesterfield, UK.
I uploaded it to a site to identify the stars which is shown via the green annotations in the image below - however I've not been able to identify what looks like a galaxy next to it (in the red square):

I'm very new to astronomy so have been relying solely on various interactive star map websites so far, none of which have shown anything in that location when I set the time/date/location as described above.
Any suggestions welcomed!

What lens are you using? Most likely just an out of focus reflection of the bright star bouncing of something within the lens.

@TomCarpenter it's a NIKKOR Z DX 50-250mm f/4.5-6.3 VR - attached to a Nikon Z 50.

Do you have a UV filter on the lens by any chance?

Nope - just the lens as is. Not sure if this would make any difference, but I took several photos from the same spot over 20 mins or so and the reflection/whatever it is appeared to be moving/rotating with the star.

Unlikely. Here is the same view from the SDSS g-band survey. Nothing to be seen at the same location.

